# GAE Blobstore Error: NOT_FOUND servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, blobstore

I'm trying to user the BlobstoreService in order to upload images to my application.
According to the GAE API this is how you should do it:

```
<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My problem is that I cannot use JSP because I'm using phonegap to create an android app and JSPs are not supported so I do this in another way, I have one servlet that receive the request, genarated the URL and forward the request to the generated URL like this:

GetBlobstoreServiceUrlServlet:

```
String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/AddDogPictureServlet");
int ahUploadIndex = url.indexOf("/_ah/upload");
url = url.substring(ahUploadIndex);
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher(url);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

This is working perfectly when I run it on my local computer but when I upload it to the GAE I'm getting "Error: NOT_FOUND" on this servlet only.

I have other serlets and all of them are working fine.

I checked the web.xml file and the servlet mapped correctly (otherwise it would not worked locally):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetBlobstoreServiceUrlServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlets.BlobstoreServlets.GetBlobstoreServiceUrlServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetBlobstoreServiceUrlServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetBlobstoreServiceUrlServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is there another way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, in production, the generated blob upload Urls (`createUploadUrl(..)`) are on servers separate from your app servers. OTOH `requestDispatcher.forward(..)` only works within the same servlet container. This works on development server because blob upload urls are simulated and run in the same servlet container.

The solution is either to:

1. forward the whole request via Url Fetch (which makes a full new outgoing Http request), or
2. preferably make upload in two steps: first get Upload url from server, then upload blob to that url.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, it is working in 2 steps, getting the URL and then submitting to this URL.